# No aparece instalar las librerías en sugerencias

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en `C#`, el cuál tengo un código que es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero dice que faltan librerías y presiono `Control + .` , pero no me aparece la opción de instalar la librería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado en otro ordenador y si me da la opción. No sé cuál podría ser el problema, gracias!

Comment: Mi conclusión es que el problema es el ordenador.

Comment: Sí, pero porqué jeje , eso es lo que me gustaría saber

Comment: Es que soy programador, no soy técnico de PC's. Lo siento.

Comment: ¿Qué diferencias hay con el otro ordenador? ¿Mismas versiones de VS Instaladas? ¿Mismas variables de entorno? ¿Mismo framework instalado?

Comment: Eso es, misma versión de vs y mismo SDK etc...

Comment: Intenta reparar el ide, desde el mismo visual studio installer lo puedes realizar.

Answer (score 0):

Esas son las dependencias de tu solución que van gestionadas vía nuget
Abre es explorador de soluciones
seleccionas la solución y click derecho sobre ella

Ahí seleccionas: Administrador de paquetes NuGet para la solución.

Ahí instala las que necesitas.

Comment: sí pero debería sugerirlas con control + "." poniendome enfima de una librería como en la foto no?

Comment: Esto no responde la pregunta, porque IMHO la pregunta no tiene respuesta, al ser una pregunta demasiado genérica y en todo caso un error que no se puede reproducir, por falta de detalles.